# HTML Alphabetic pattern doesnt work

Tags: html

I have made a form and works fine, but it doesnt validate correctly with and alphabetical pattern though it does validate the numerical pattern. I dont manage to make it work and every site i have seen says the same pattern. Here is the full form its validated through the w3c markup validation and i also tried running it in the snippet but it didnt work either, dont know if it has something to do but i am using a spanish display keyboard but havent use any spanish special character yet like ñ,á,é,í,ó,ú.

```html
<form class="form23" action="insert-paciente.php" method="post"> <!-- formulario dentro de las pestañas  -->
<input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="C.I" name="ci_p"  pattern="[0-9]{7,8}" title="Introduzca una cedula valida" required/> <br>
<input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Primer nombre"  name="primer_nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Ingrese solo caracteres alfabeticos" required/><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Segundo nombre" name="segundo_nombre" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Ingrese solo caracteres alfabeticos"/><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Primer Apellido"  name="primer_apellido" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Ingrese solo caracteres alfabeticos" required/><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Segundo Apellido"  name="segundo_apellido" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Ingrese solo caracteres alfabeticos"/><br>
<select id="select1" name="sexo" required>
<option value="">Sexo</option>
<option value="M">M</option>
<option value="F">F</option>
</select><br>
<select id="select1" name="tipo_p" required>
<option value="">Tipo de paciente</option>
<option value="Personal">Personal</option>
<option value="Estudiante">Estudiante</option>
<option value="Atencion a la comunidad">Comunidad</option>
</select><br>
<select id="select1" name="tipo_personal" >
<option value="">Tipo de Personal</option>
<option value="Administrativo">Personal</option>
<option value="Docente">Estudiante</option>
<option value="Obrero">Comunidad</option>
</select><br>
<select id="select1" name="especialidad" >
<option value="">Especialidad</option>
<option value="Administracion">Administracion</option>
<option value="Agroalientacion">Agroalientacion</option>
<option value="Contaduria publica">Contaduria publica</option>
<option value="Electricidad">Electricidad</option>
<option value="Informatica">Informatica</option>
<option value="Mantenimiento">Mantenimiento</option>
<option value="Mecanica">Mecanica</option>
<option value="Procesos quimicos">Procesos quimicos</option>
<option value="Quimica">Quimica</option><option value="Procesos quimicos">Comunidad</option>
<option value="Seguridad alimentaria">Seguridad alimentaria</option>
</select><br>
<input id="text2" type="text" placeholder="Alergias"  name="alergias" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Ingrese solo caracteres alfabeticos" required /><br>
<label id="lb2" for="text2">Fecha de nacimiento</label> <br>
<input id="text2" type="date"  name="fecha" required /> <br>
 <input id="text2" type="submit" value="Registrar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Which fields wont validate, and what input are you expecting to validate?

Comment: The only field that is validating correctly is the "ci_p" one with the pattern="[0-9]{7,8}",and the option inputs that are only required. Any text field with the pattern="[A-Za-z]" as "primer_nombre","segundo_nombre,"primer_apellido","segundo_apellido" or"alergias" wont validate correctly as i have tried with alphabetical, numerical and special characters and everything make it pop the "use a valid format" alert.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field with sort order and update query using order by sort-order.

Comment: could you explain a bit more? i dont understand this answer